# How to find a basis for the vector space of polynomials s.t. $f(-1) = f(2)$ of deg equal or less than $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following [vector space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dysas.jpg) and I want to find a basis for it and after that complete it to be a basis of the entire vector space os polynomials of degree $2$ or less.

I got the following basis $(1, x, -x^2 )$ by equating $a-b+c = a+2b+4c$ an getting $b=-c$ but the second polynomial doesn’t fulfill $p(-1) = p(2)$ so I guess it is wrong.

Also how could I complete it to the basis of the full $R2[x]$ vector space?

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: $-1-(-1)^2=-2$ and $2-(2^2)=-2$

Answer (score 1):

Calculate $p(-1)$ and $p(2)$ again. They do indeed become equal for $p(x) = x-x^2$.

You also need to prove that your two polynomials indeed span *all* the space you're after, and not just a part of it.

As for completing it to a basis for all of $\Bbb R_2[x]$, just find a polynomial *not* having the property you want, add that to the basis, and see whether that covers all of $\Bbb R_2[x]$, or whether you need more.